# Access store vuex in quasar for meta

Tags: vuex, server-side-rendering, meta, prefetch, quasar

I'm using quasar in SSR mode and I would like to implement meta data. Quasar has a plugin for meta data and I wanted to use it.

For now my project is quite simple, I have a page product (/product/:id) which display product information.

In the page Product, I use prefetch to fetch Data from a remote API base on the param id.

```
<template>
  <q-page padding>
      <div v-if="product">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <span v-html="product.description"/>
      </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import store from '../store'
export default {
  name: 'Product',
  async preFetch ({ store, currentRoute }) {
    let id = currentRoute.params.id
    if (typeof store.getters['product/getProduct'](id) === 'undefined') {
      let promise = store.dispatch('product/fetchProduct', id)
      await promise.then({})
    }
  },
  computed: {
    product () {
      return this.$store.getters['product/getProduct'](this.$route.params.id)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

So far everything work find. I have my data setted in the store before rendering. But now I wanted to had a meta title. But in meta how can I have acces to the store and route.params.id.

```
<script>

export default {
  name 'Product',
  ...
  meta: {
    title: store.getters['product/getProductMetaTitle'](route.params.id)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? I'm facing the same problem